# Can't change journal mode in SQLite on Android

Tags: android, sqlite, sqlite-journal-mode

I'm using Android 6.0 and SQLite 3.8.10.2
I have a problem with changing journal mode for my db connection.

```
Cursor cursor = null;
cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery("PRAGMA journal_mode", null);
Boolean d = cursor.moveToFirst();
String gg = cursor.getString(0);
cursor.close();

mDatabase.rawQuery("PRAGMA journal_mode=DELETE", null);

cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery("PRAGMA journal_mode", null);
Boolean dd = cursor.moveToFirst();
String xx = cursor.getString(0);
cursor.close();
```

First I check `journal_mode` and value is 'PERSIST'
Then I set `journal_mode=DELETE` and check again, but value of `xx` variable is still PERSIST.
I need to change journal_mode because I have to sync db between multiple devices.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I have to write `journal_mode=Delete` instead of `journal_mode=DELETE`.
Very strange, because [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode) writes everything in capital letters.

Comment: Capitalization makes no difference whatsoever to SQLite. The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode) says that "if the journal mode could not be changed, the original journal mode is returned".

Comment: @GigaKatowice did you try `execSQL`? When trying out VACUUMN, I think, I came across issues. Basically I use `rawQuery` for retrieving and `execSQL` for setting PRAGMA's.

Comment: @MikeT Yes, I tried execSQL but it throws an exception.